# JavaScript last element of HTML collection not defined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to create a bookable product, where upon selected (= selectbox) a room type, the picture changes to that specific room with good old javascript.

the interesting part is that it works for the first element of the HTML collection, but the last element is giving an undefined and makes it impossible to override.
I am not getting why that is. I tried via the console log to view what I am missing, but I see nothing problematic.

HTML collection:

```
0: <a href="https://staging.deloftli…09/Steck-coachruimte.jpg" hidefocus="true" style="outline: currentcolor none medium;">​
1: <img class="zoomImg" role="presentation" alt="" src="https://staging.deloftli…09/Steck-coachruimte.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:…none; max-height: none;">
```

I have the following script:

```
<script id="bookingschanges">
      var activities = document.getElementById("wc_bookings_field_resource");
      var image = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-product-gallery__image")[0].children[0].firstChild;
      var zoompic = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-product-gallery__image")[0].children[1];

activities.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var options = activities.querySelectorAll("option");
});

activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if(activities.value == "1949")
    {
        image.src = "https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Podkas.jpeg";
        image.srcset = ""
        zoompic.scr = "https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Podkas.jpeg";
    }
console.log(image);     
console.log(zoompic);
});</script>
```

The first element (image) is correct, the second element (zoompic) gives undefined.

To see it live, go to https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/product/vergaderruimte-huren/ and check the console log.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Show us what your markup is? In the HTML you've shown there is no class `woocommerce-product-gallery__image`

Comment: Is this typo `zoompic.scr = ....` It seems you meant `zoompic.src`

Comment: Also, `zoompic` seems to be undefined in general. Plus the way you're changing the current gallery image is not a good approach because you aren't telling the gallery about this change; hovering the changed image shows the gallery panning across the old one. Check the gallery plugin for a way to properly switch the image.

Comment: For one of them you have `.children[0].firstChild` (=`.children[0].children[0]`) while for the other one you have `.children[1]` - one layer less. Did you maybe mean `.children[0].children[1]`?

Comment: Thanks all. I answer your questions 1 by 1.
@Terry: the markup is visible on the page, but it is a lot. So i included the link

Comment: @abhishekkannojia: you are right, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ChrisG: You are right and i wanted to improve the current approach, but that was meant after i run into the described problem.

Comment: @CherryDT: No the markup is like that, its a bit strange but the first element has an <a> on layer above the <img>, the other doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable zoompic is not defined at the time the variable is declared (its called before the element is created on loading, debug the page and refresh it to see) you will need to use an onload event listener.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

As someone else has suggested it would be better to call the image change function in the original javascript to change the image that is selected and you will avoid any issues. This might not be easy though if it is an external library.

EDIT: Added an example of onLoad

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var activities = document.getElementById("wc_bookings_field_resource");
  var image = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-product-gallery__image")[0].children[0].firstChild;
  var zoompic = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-product-gallery__image")[0].children[1];

  activities.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var options = activities.querySelectorAll("option");
  });

  activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (activities.value == "1949") {
      image.src = "https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Podkas.jpeg";

      image.srcset = "https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Podkas.jpeg 768w";

      zoompic.src = "https://staging.deloftlisse.nl/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Podkas.jpeg";
    }
    console.log(image);
    console.log(zoompic);
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i added a set timeout to the function and indeed it works now. I am not a big expert in javascript, better in Php to be frankly...

Comment: @Kees just be aware that with timing instead of doing onLoad if a persons browser takes too long to load it may fail (slow connection). Its possible that someone may click on the dropdown also before 1 second is elapsed but unlikely.

Comment: Thanks, nice example too btw...